# Error installing the MongoDB dependencies for the Node.js application

Tags: node.js, json, mongodb, npm

Please can anybody help me in solving this error.
While installing the package it says unexpected end of JSON input
[image]

This the log file while installing the MongoDB package:

```
    0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [
1 verbose cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe',
1 verbose cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js',
1 verbose cli   'install',
1 verbose cli   'mongodb'
1 verbose cli ]
2 info using npm@6.14.8
3 info using node@v14.15.0
4 verbose npm-session b371e7f3c99437f2
5 silly install loadCurrentTree
6 silly install readLocalPackageData
7 http fetch GET 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/mongodb 9966ms (from cache)
8 silly fetchPackageMetaData error for mongodb@latest Unexpected end of JSON input while parsing near '...":"0.7.3","github3":"'
9 timing stage:rollbackFailedOptional Completed in 1ms
10 timing stage:runTopLevelLifecycles Completed in 10061ms
11 verbose stack SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input while parsing near '...":"0.7.3","github3":"'
11 verbose stack     at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
11 verbose stack     at parseJson (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\json-parse-better-errors\index.js:7:17)
11 verbose stack     at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-fetch-npm\src\body.js:96:50
11 verbose stack     at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:93:5)
12 verbose cwd C:\Users\sukruti\OneDrive\desktop\FruitsProject
13 verbose Windows_NT 10.0.18363
14 verbose argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "mongodb"
15 verbose node v14.15.0
16 verbose npm  v6.14.8
17 error Unexpected end of JSON input while parsing near '...":"0.7.3","github3":"'
18 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "fruitsproject",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "app.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC"
}
```

Comment: Without showing us your package.json, it's hard to debug. Try deleting node_modules and running "npm install" again. You can also update your version of NodeJS if you aren't dependent on v12.18.1.

Comment: @JordanQuartermain I updated the NodeJS application, deleted the node_modules and reinstalled it. I get the same error while installing MongoDB package. I added the package.json file, if any other files is required please mention.

Comment: Can you please attempt clearing the NPM cache? Run the following command, "npm cache clean --force". Delete your node_modules and re-run "npm install". Be sure to run termindal (or cmd) as admin too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please run the following with admin privileges. Please delete node_modules folder and delete your package-lock.json (if it exists)

```
$ npm cache clean --force
$ npm install mongodb --save
```